# Strange delay for touch events in UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, opengl-es

I am working on an OpenGL application for the iPhone...
My app has only 2 views:
An OpenGL view and, as a subview for the OpenGL view, a view with the sole purpose of catching touch events...
The problem is that after about 10-15 minutes of keeping the app running on the device, I get a big (0.5s-1s) delay between every touchesMoved:withEvent: call
The animation runs smooth, and CPU usage is also not the problem (10% at most)
I have no idea what might be causing this

Comment: you don't need to use subview to catch touch events.

Comment: Yes... I know I could catch them directly in the OpenGL view, but it's more convenient this way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is weird, eh.

This happens ON THE DEVICE right?  When you are not running tethered from XCode?

I would guess you are using up a lot of memory, either a leak or just in some way using up more and more memory as time goes on.

Are you familiar with the various memory tools to watch what is going on?

Also, what about this:  launch a few other large apps that remain in the background.  Run your app until the problem exhibits. Then, kill the other apps.  Does the problem suddenly go away? If so that would suggest you're low on memory.

Would be interested to hear.

Comment: It only happened when running tethered from XCode... I couldn't test it untethered, because it takes quite a while for the problem to appear... Memory is not the problem... I checked with Instruments for leaks, and according to both Instruments and top, it doesn't use more than 3-4MB  Still... I'll try doing it in low memory conditions, but I don't think that's the problem

Comment: In fact it was a memory problem... But not with my app... I had a leak in a Springboard tweak I was also working on... Opps... Sorry :D